# Simplifying Complex Numbers that contain physical units

Tags: complex, assumptions, simplifying-expressions, physicalconstants-package

I am trying to evaluate the following:

```
Simplify[Meter Nano Re[(a + I b)/(Meter Nano)], Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]]
```

However, Mathematica returns:

```
Meter*Nano*Re[(a + I*b)/(Meter*Nano)]
```

And if I try:

```
Convert[Meter Nano Re[(a + I b)/(Meter Nano)], 1]
```

I get the error:

```
Convert::incomp: "Incompatible units in Meter Nano Re[(a+I b)/(Meter Nano)] and 1."
```

How can I factor out the "Meter Nano" from within Re[] and simplify the above to:

`a`

One solution:

As suggested by rcollyer, use ComplexExpand:

`ComplexExpand[Meter Nano Re[(a + I b)/(Meter Nano)]]`

which gives

`a`

Note: [ComplexExpand](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html), as written above, assumes `a` and `b` are `Reals`.

Comment: Have you tried `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: Please use the code markup, as per my edits, to display code. $\TeX$, while pretty, does not copy well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ComplexExpand[Meter Nano Re[(a + I b)/(Meter Nano)]]
```

> a

As a side note: in v9, the `` Miscellaneous`Units` `` package that you are using (and which you don't mention in your question) has been superseded by the new built-in unit system. The above expression would have been simplified without `Simplify`:

```
Quantity[1, "Nanometers"]Re[Quantity[a + I*b, "Nanometers"^(-1)]]
```

> -Im[b] + Re[a]